# Character escaping in templates

Tags: django, django-templates, django-urls

[The good explanation of the roots of this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21764909/template-url-reversal-escaping-surt-arguments)

Apparently, there is no obvious way to use some special characters in the Django template URLs. For example # always gets converted into %23.

The thing is, I want to use HTML5 video tag to play videos, and the way to control start and end time of the clip is to append #t=[start,end] at the end of the *scr* argument.

For example :

```
<video><source src = "/static/video.mp4#t=5,10"> </source></video>
```

wont work if # gets translated into %23.

As I understand, there is no clean general solution for this problem, but may be there is a workaround specific to my situation?

Comment: Are you sure? It shouldn't and it doesn't really: http://i.imgur.com/1FTU7dp.png

Comment: here is how it looks in the terminal: `[14/Oct/2016 17:29:02] "GET /static/video.mp4 HTTP/1.1" 404 6365184 `, note that #t=5,10 was dropped by django. Here is an example (just for illustration purposes) of "/static/video.mp4^t=5,10" gets translated to `[14/Oct/2016 17:29:02] "GET /static/video.mp4%5Et=5,10 HTTP/1.1" 404 1665`